# Use v-for create components inside div in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, vue-component

I want to loop over a json object and create for each element a component which props are also from that object

Inside the div a inserted

```
<div class="row" v-for="item in projectsJson">
```

I use a div to get the bootstrap class.

This does create two divs instead of one. Desired result would would be one div container filled with components.

I used the same logic from react is this working different in vue?

```
jsonObj = 
[
  {
    "name": "proj1",
    "descr": "stuff",
    "stack": ["which", "other lib"],
    "imgPath": "."
  },
  {
    "name": "proj2",
    "descr": "stuffsss",
    "stack": ["which ", "other "],
    "imgPath": "."
  }
]

<template>
 <div class="row" v-for="item in projectsJson">
        <project-comp
        :project_name="item.name" />
      </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue.js, `v-for` applies to the DOM element on which the attribute is. Also, don't forget the [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)
You should do :

```js
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <project-comp 
      v-for="item in projectsJson" 
      :project_name="item.name" 
      :key="project.name" <!-- The key should be unique in the array, use name if it is unique, or use id -->
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This answer is same an mine. The solution for the answer is to move the  v-for to component level. Not with the key for `v-for`. the user should have considered the usage of key in his first imlementation itself.

Comment: @Nitheesh what's wrong with providing additional information for the OP?

Comment: Additional information never ends. So anyone can add another answer on top of your implementation aswell.

Comment: @Nitheesh I added the key in my answer because it felt wrong to provide vue.js code in my answer that would cause Vue.js warnings

Answer (score 3):

If you need a single div with class `row` and all the child component inside that, you should move the `v-for` to the component instead of the div.

React also behaves in same way. To which component you apply the loop, it will repeat in DOM.

```
<div class="row" >
    <project-comp
        v-for="item in projectsJson"
        :project_name="item.name" />
</div>
```